# How to remove attachments from received mail in ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attachment, actionmailer, mailman-gem

I'm using Mailman to pull e-mails from a POP3 server and process them. But, before processing, I want to ignore any attachments that they might have.

I'm looking everywhere to see if Mail supports this, but don't seems so. It looks like I can only see the attachments, but not remove them. Is it so? If yes, is there any workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an open issue for this feature in the Mail issue tracker: [#33](https://github.com/mikel/mail/issues/33).

You can try to use the suggested code and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Don't seems ideal, but at least I can go on... :)